# sequelize.js N:M through relationships, delete cascade

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize.js v1.7.9. With Express.js 4

I have the following relationships:

```
User hasMany UserRoles
User hasMany Roles through UserRoles

UserRoles belongsTo user
UserRoles belongsTo role

Role hasMany UserRoles
Role hasMany Users through UserRoles
```

In Rails, we can simply say dependent: :destroy, and when either `User` or `Role` are deleted, the related `UserRole` rows are destroyed as well, however this is not working with Sequelize.js.

I am explicitly creating the join table with migrations, I've set the onDelete: 'CASCADE' on the join tables. But it is not behaving like it is supposed to.

**TL;DR,** How to get delete CASCADE to work like Rails ActiveRecord `dependent: :destroy`

My code is as of the following:

user.js:

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var user = sequelize.define('user',
    {
      name: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    {
      classMethods: {
        associate: function (models) {
          user.hasMany(models.role, {through: models.userRole})
          user.hasMany(models.userRole, {onDelete: 'CASCADE', hooks: true})
        }
      }
    }
  )
  return user
}
```

role.js:

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var role = sequelize.define('role',
    {
      name: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    {
      classMethods: {
        associate: function (models) {
          role.hasMany(models.userRole, {onDelete: 'CASCADE', hooks: true})
          role.hasMany(models.user, {through: models.userRole})
        }
      }
    }
  )
  return role
}
```

userRole.js:

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var userRole = sequelize.define('userRole',
    {
      userId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      roleId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    {
      classMethods: {
        associate: function (models) {
          userRole.belongsTo(models.user)
          userRole.belongsTo(models.role)
        }
      }
    }
  )
  return userRole
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately n:m cascades do not work properly in 1.7. They are added by default in 2.0

Comment: Can you give an example in 2.0?

Comment: The code you posted works out of the box in 2.0, you don't need to add anything to get cascading constraints. Unless you are going to query the userRole table directly you don't need `role.hasMany(models.userRole, {onDelete: 'CASCADE', hooks: true})` or `userRole.belongsTo(models.user)` either, the `through` part is enough